# Implenting simultaneous bindings

Tags: lisp, scheme

I'm writing a Lisp (code at [GitHub](https://github.com/chris-taylor/Haskeme)) and I want to implement local bindings. Currently I have two syntaxes:

```
(let <var> <val> <expr>)
```

for binding a single variable or function, and

```
(with (<var1> <val1> ... <varN> <valN>) <expr>)
```

to bind multiple values at once.

At present, the bindings are evaluated sequentially, and each new function binding retains a copy of the environment it was defined in, so `<var2>` can refer to `<var1>` but not vice-versa.

I would like to modify the code so that when binding multiple values at once you effectively have simultaneous binding. For example, I would like to be able to write (this is a trivial example, but it should illustrate the idea):

```
(define (h y)
  (with ((f x) (if (eq? x 0) #t (g (- x 1)))
         (g x) (if (eq? x 0) #f (f (- x 1))))
  (f y))
```

At the moment this code doesn't run - `g` closes over `f`, but not the other way around.

Is there a canonical way to implement simultaneous binding in Lisp?

Comment: You introduce `with` as a variable binding construct, but then in the next example int morphs into a lexical function binding construct. Is that really the case and is it distinguishe on the `<var1>` being a symbol, or a list?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yeah, in my implementation `let` and `with` bind both variables (if `<var>` is a symbol) and lexical functions (if `<var>` is a list). They call exactly the same underlying functions - see lines 114-139 of EvalApply.hs in my github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) there's a section on [internal definitions](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.6) which covers  this subject. In particular, the exercises 4.16, 4.18, 4.19 tell you how to implement different strategies for achieving simultaneous definitions.

The syntax is a bit different, but the idea in the book boils down to transforming this code:

```
(lambda <vars>
  (define u <e1>)
  (define v <e2>)
  <e3>)
```

Into this code:

```
(lambda <vars>
  (let ((u '*unassigned*)
        (v '*unassigned*))
    (set! u <e1>)
    (set! v <e2>)
    <e3>))
```

The same idea applies to your `with` special form. Take a look at the linked book for more implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to SICP. If local bindings are just code transformations, then maybe `let` and `with` shouldn't be primitives, but macros instead. What do you think?

Comment: @ChrisTaylor that's a good idea. In that way the core of the language remains simple, and other special forms can be implemented as syntactic transformations using macros. In fact, in SICP `let`, `let*`, `letrec`, etc. are implemented as syntactic transformations (at the interpreter level, not with macros)

Answer (score 1):

In `(with (a (+ 2 2)))` we are binding `a` to the value of the expression `(+ 2 2)`, so `a` becomes 4. But in `(with ((f x) (+ x x)))` we are doing something else: we are binding `f` to a function. This is a syntactic sugar for `(with (f (lambda (x) (+ x x))))`.

To handle this situation, you have to process the bindings in two passes. First collect all the variables and create the environment which contains all of them. Then evaluate the initializing experssions and store their values in the corresponding variables. The evaluation of these expressions takes place **in** that environment, so every expression has visibility over all the variables. The initialization is done by assignment. The variables can be initially `nil` or have some trap value which blows up if they are accessed.

Comment: Good luck with the assignment in Haskell. :)

Comment: You can see that this is the same answer as Óscar's. You can do this by a code transformation to the non-mutually-recursive `let` construct; what I described is a strategy for interpreting it directly which amounts to the same thing.